# Parsing of comma-separated list for \foreach

Tags: foreach, comma-separated-list

I am using PGF's `\foreach` on comma-separated list where the items may contain spaces; each item can be enclosed in `{...}` if it contains space, that works fine. Now, what happens when there is only a single item in the list? Curiously, whitespace has (for me unexpected) influence here.

An explanation, and better yet, a way to avoid this type of input fragility, would be much appreciated.

This is parsed correcrtly:

```
\fooList{items={{foo, foo}
    }
}
```

but not this one:

```
\fooList{items={{foo, foo}
}}
```

or this one:

```
\fooList{items={{foo, foo}}}
```

```latex
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{pgffor}
\pgfkeys{
    /foo/.is family,
    /foo,
    items/.store in=\fooItems,
    items/.initial=\undefined
}
\newcommand{\fooList}[1]{
    \pgfkeys{/foo/.cd,#1}
    \begin{enumerate}
        \foreach [var=\content] in \fooItems{\item\content}
    \end{enumerate}
}
\parindent=0pt
\begin{document}
    Comma-separated list works fine for two items:
    \fooList{
        items={
            {foo, foo},
            {bar, bar}
        }
    }
    Single item is understood when written with trailing newlines
    \fooList{items={{foo, foo}
        }
    }
    It gets incorrectly split when written like this:
    \fooList{items={{foo, foo}
    }}
    And also when fully compacted:
    \fooList{items={{foo, foo}}}
\end{document}
```

[image: PDF]

Comment: Unrelated, but maybe better use `\usepackage` instead of `\include` in the preamble.

Comment: Oops, that was my fingers on autopilot :) Fixed.

Answer (score 3):

I'm afraid there is nothing you can do about the bugs in `pgfkeys`... There are <s>two possibilities</s> no viable solutions if you want to stick to it:

- always put a space before the opening or after the closing brace (`\fooItems{items={{one,two}} }` or `\fooItems{items= {{one,two}}}` -- or both)
- put an extra brace around the value (`\fooItems{items={{{one,two}}}}`)

**EDIT:** Unfortunately, this is still not correct because of a second bug in `pgfkeys`, it strips one set of braces too much if there are no spaces around the value (this would be fixed by both suggestions) and then it might strip *a second* pair of braces when forwarding the value to the underlying command defined by the `.store in` handler (ouch!)

---

But note that there are a few key=value parsers available that don't have that brace bug (and might as well provide a csv-looping macro):

- `expkv`
- `kvsetkeys`
- `l3keys` (part of the LaTeX kernel in the `expl3` language)
- `\DeclareKeys`/`\SetKeys` (part of the LaTeX kernel)

The following demonstrates your code using `expkv` (Disclaimer: I'm the package author) and `l3keys` (in the `expl3` language):

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{expkv-def}
\ekvdefinekeys{foo}
  {
     store items = \fooItems
    ,initial items = \undefined
  }
\newcommand\fooList[1]
  {%
    \ekvset{foo}{#1}%
    \begin{enumerate}
      % no automatic detection of a variable storing the list, so we need to
      % manually expand it.
      \expandafter\ekvcsvloop\expandafter\item\expandafter{\fooItems}%
    \end{enumerate}
  }

\ExplSyntaxOn
\keys_define:nn { eudoxos / foo }
  {
     items .clist_set:N = \l__eudoxos_items_clist
    ,items .initial:n = \undefined
  }
\NewDocumentCommand \FooList { m }
  {
    \keys_set:nn { eudoxos / foo } {#1}
    \begin{enumerate}
      \clist_map_function:NN \l__eudoxos_items_clist \item
    \end{enumerate}
  }
\ExplSyntaxOff

\parindent=0pt
\begin{document}
\section{Using \texttt{expkv}}
    Comma-separated list works fine for two items:
    \fooList{
        items={
            {foo, foo},
            {bar, bar}
        }
    }
    Single item is understood when written with trailing newlines
    \fooList{items={{foo, foo}
        }
    }
    It gets incorrectly split when written like this:
    \fooList{items={{foo, foo}
    }}
    And also when fully compacted:
    \fooList{items={{foo, foo}}}
    \clearpage

\section{Using \texttt{l3keys}}
    Comma-separated list works fine for two items:
    \FooList{
        items={
            {foo, foo},
            {bar, bar}
        }
    }
    Single item is understood when written with trailing newlines
    \FooList{items={{foo, foo}
        }
    }
    It gets incorrectly split when written like this:
    \FooList{items={{foo, foo}
    }}
    And also when fully compacted:
    \FooList{items={{foo, foo}}}
\end{document}
```